# Мультиязычность Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся проблемой мультиязычности сайта на wordpress. Многие плагины дают возможность менять посты, страницы, те которые через консоль меняются. а то что статичная в шаблоне index.php не могу поменять. Посоветуйте как можно это сделать, шяс использую плагин Bogo

Comment: Все плагины мультиязычности работают только с контентом в базе. Вам надо разделить шаблон страницы и её контент, поместив его в базу.

Comment: я поискал в интернете, нужно сделать папку languages в корне темы и с помощью программы poedit переводит

Comment: это в том случае, если у вас вывод контента идет через gettext - функции. И к плагинам мультиязычности это отношения не имеет

Comment: как разделить шаблон страницы и еёё контент, поместив его в базу?

Comment: Как все делают - через ACF-поля или блочные редакторы